# Can't get simple property editor to be used

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

A have a set of custom components that we use to encapsulate some functionality and I'm trying to add a custom property editor and can't seem to work out how to get it to apply.  Our registration unit has the following code in it

```
type
  THexWordProperty = class(TIntegerProperty)
  public
    function GetValue: string; override;
  end;

{ THexProperty }

function THexWordProperty.GetValue: string;
begin
  Result := '$'+IntToHex(GetOrdValue, 4);
end;
```

followed by the following call

`RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TPeripheralMask),nil,'',THexWordProperty);`

in the registration procedure.

Despite rebuilding the package, uninstalling, reinstalling and restarting Delphi I can't get any of my `TPeripheralMask` properties to display any different.  As far as I can see this is the simplest possible property editor as I'm simply trying to get what is a simple ordinal property to display in a different (but still valid for input) form.

The actual property type is defined simply as `type  TPeripheralMask = Word;`, is there something I should be doing to support additional RTTI for this type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type  
  TPeripheralMask = Word;
```

This is a type alias. That means that `TPeripheralMask` and `Word` refer to the same type. You need to make a new type.

```
type  
  TPeripheralMask = type Word;
```

---

The relevant [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_Types) says the following:

> When you declare a type that is identical to an existing type, the
>   compiler treats the new type identifier as an alias for the old one.
>   Thus, given the declarations:
>
> ```
> type TValue = Real;
> var
>   X: Real;
>   Y: TValue;
> ```
>
> X and Y are of the same type; at run time, there is no way to
>   distinguish TValue from Real. This is usually of little consequence,
>   but if your purpose in defining a new type is to utilize runtime type
>   information, for example, to associate a property editor with
>   properties of a particular type - the distinction between 'different
>   name' and 'different type' becomes important. In this case, use the
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> type newTypeName = type KnownType
> ```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple, all working now.